# Extract value from type constant in typescript

Tags: typescript

Given the following type definition, is there a way to extract the constant value from the type ?

```
type Dummy = {
  type: "dummy"
}
```

Something like `Extract<Dummy["type"]>`

Comment: Types are erased at "compile" time and do not exist at runtime.. So you can't get value from type

Comment: You can go the other way around: define a const and get its type

Answer (score 4):

No, types are removed from your source at compile time, so there would be nothing to pull the value from.

You can get a type from a constant, however.

```
const dummy = { type: "Dummy" } as const
// `as const` get `{ type: "Dummy" }` instead of `{ type: string }`
type Dummy = typeof dummy
```

Comment: You'll need `as const` to keep literal type (prevent widening to `string`). `const dummy = { type: "dummy" } as const` or `const dummy = { type: "dummy" as const }`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

Comment: Question was related to extract the value directly from type for discrimination union, without having a concern on type constant being changed over time.